# Как правильно определить покерную комбинацию из 5 карт(конкретно проблема с тройником)

Tags: java, коллекции

Есть класс колода(Deck), из него в случайном порядке выдается пять карт. Далее необходимо проверить на наличие покерной комбинации.Все в порядке только вот с тройником беда. Собственно определить тройник не так то и сложно, проблема в том, что я должен знать какие карты образовали тройник, а из моей реализации не получается учесть самую первую карту и поэтому метод выдает только фулхаусы и каре.

```
 public boolean isThreeOfKind() {
    ArrayList<Card> cardsToZero = new ArrayList<>();//сюда кладутся карты тройника 
    HashSet<String> rankKeys = new HashSet<>();
    for (Card c : cards) {
        /*1.берем ранг карты
         *2.если есть такой же ранг откладываем в лист cardsToZero
         *3. если нет то в rankKeys
         4.повторяем. если cardstozero будет = 3 то это точно тройник*/
        if (rankKeys.contains(c.getStringRank())) {
            cardsToZero.add(c);
        } else {
            rankKeys.add(c.getStringRank());
        }
        if (cardsToZero.size()==3){
            //int rezultZero = cardsToZero.get(0).getRank();
            //rezultZero = getTotal() - rezultZero*3;
            //System.out.println("from method rezult :" + rezultZero);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

вот класс Card

```
public class Card {
private Suit suit;
private Rank rank;
//private StraightRank straightRank;

public Card(Rank rank, Suit suit){
    this.rank = rank;
    this.suit = suit;
   // this.straightRank = straightRank;
}
public String printRank(){
    return rank.getStringRank();
}

public String getSuit(){
    return suit.getSuit();
}

public int getRank(){
    return rank.getRank();
}
public String getStringRank(){
    return rank.getStringRank();
}

public String toString(){
    String str = "";
        str += rank.getStringRank() + suit.getSuit();
    return str;
}
}
```

Comment: допишите логику в более простом виде, не каждый программист играет в покер ;)

Comment: логика проста, для каждой из пяти карт проверяется его ранг(2,3,4..туз, король) если есть ранг то вносится в список, если список равен трем то это тройник

Comment: Если честно, я совсем не понял вашу проблему. После прохода по списку cards у вас есть сет из оригинальных ранков и лист из повторяющихся ранков. И что тут не так?

Comment: Пожалуйста, разделите этот вопрос на два. Здесь не допускается задавать несколько вопросов в одном.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я вас правильно понял, то ваши проблемы с `Map` может решить то, что называется multimap. По сути это штука, которая на один ключ может привязать множество значений. Такая реализация из коробки отсутствует в стандартной библиотеке Java, однако давно существует в коллекциях  Guava или Apache.

Вместе с тем, если вы пользуетесь Java 8, то у вас тоже есть выход, выглядит он примерно так:

```
map.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(value);
```

Мало того, совет использовать `computeIfAbsent` для создания мультикарты явно указан в документации - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-

Comment: какая то беда с импортом библиотеки в проект т.к. у меня простой (неMaven) проект, добавить через зависимости не получится, а простой импорт не определяет. import com.google.guava.*; что не так?

Comment: Я не знаю, какая у вас система сборки, по полагаю, что Ant. Если вы пользуетесь указанным вариантом map.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(value); , то Вам ничего импортировать не надо. Это решение для Java 8. Ежели у вас версия Java ниже и вы хотите пользоваться сторонней библиотекой, то заходите на мавен репозиторий, ищите сответствующую библиотеку в поисковой строке, выбираете из спписка найденных версий. Там есть ссылки для всех систем сборки. Кроме того, вы можете скачать jar-файл с нужной библиотекой. Если у вас Ant, скачайте jar-файл и подключите его как библиотеку руками.

Comment: ссылка для guava коллекций  - https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava/23.3-jre

Comment: разобрался, спасибо! по поводу лямбда - шикарная вещь конечно..

Comment: не за что, пользуйтесь. у меня недавно в проекте примерно аналогичная задача была - мультимеп потребовался. все решилось именно с помощью Java 8. guava и прочее - это , конечно, хорошо,но подключать библиотеку из-за одного мультимепа мало радости.

Answer (score 0):

```
другой вопрос как в Map<K, List<V>> можно поочередно добавлять элементы в List?
```

Условно:

```
Map<Key, List<Value>> map = new HashMap<>();

for (Value c : values) {
        if (!map.contains(c.getStringRank())) {           
            //в Map кладем новый List
            map.put(c.getStringRank(), new ArrayList<Value>);
        }
        //далее  берем лист из Map и добавляем значение:
        map.get(c.getStringRank()).add(c);
    }
}
```